# class loading exceptions during debugging in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, classloader

everytime I try to step into a class during eclipse debugging sessions I get a whole call stack of a ClassNotFoundException which the JVM throws during class loading. This means the call propagates through the AppClassLoader, ExtClassLoader and URLClassLoader which finally throws the exception. I can now step out this entire tree and just do a step-in again and then it'll work but I don't need to tell you that this is annoying like hell.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with my config? Interestingly enough I tried this on two fresh eclipse installations but it still happens. I thought about an exception breakpoint but there is none...